# Email Sender In PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am trying to build an email sender in PHP/MySQL where you can choose the group of people (in dropdown menu) and send them a message. I have a {users} table with emails and I am having trouble figuring out how to do groups table.

What columns should I have?
or
Any other way to do the same thing?

I would be really grateful if you could explain like you would to a beginner :)

Thank you)

Comment: It's an UML problem, not a PHP/MySQL. Say first what you tried and how do you get stuck. We can't do your job, only try to help you from precise issue you have. But you can do something like that for your problem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Comment: I understand that the question is too broad...sorry about that...but I am stuck with the logic...how to accomplish the task! Thank you for your advice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a many-to-many relationship, which will look something like this (three tables):

**group**

```
id
name
```

**user_groups**

```
id
user_id
group_id
```

**users**

```
id
name
email
```

Whenever a user is added to a group, you will insert a row into the `user_groups` table.

Have a read on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: yeah) this looks like what I am looking for) let me try this) Thank you sir)